# Actions for multiple Node selection

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-platform

To define actions for selected nodes I override the `getActions(bool b)` method of `BeanNode`. However, if I select more than one node, i get no contextual menu on rightclick. Is there a way to define actions for multiple nodes? If you know of a tutorial I missed on the subject, please link, else I´m grateful for any hints.

- The Nodes are all of the same type (and have the same actions).
- The Nodes are displayed on a `BeanTreeView`.

Comment: Can you maybe update your questions with the following info: Are you overriding `getActions()` on the Node or the NodeFactory (afaik the NodeFactory does not have a `getActions()` method)? Are all the nodes the same type (ie. do they have the same actions)? What explorer view are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely scenario that will cause the actions to be displayed during single selection but not during multi selection is that you `new` the actions each time in the `getActions(boolean b)` method. This will prevent the `findActions(Node[] nodes)` method in [`NodeOp.java`](http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/a07f3b725c40/openide.nodes/src/org/openide/nodes/NodeOp.java) from finding *common* actions for your nodes because the action instances will be different.

Rather use `SystemAction.get(Class<T> actionClass)` or something similar to get to the instances of your actions instead of creating the action instances each time.